# how to hide a row in the listview, when in the adapter, from a touch listener in the activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an activity which has a TextView button (btnChangeMode) that toggles the mode from "admin" to "guest". Depending on the mode chosen, I need to hide/show a button (btnAddListItems) within my listview row. The code i have, currently doesn't seem to be cutting it.

Code speaks easier, so here's the gist of my code:

My activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ListView> ... </ListView> <!-- which has its items populated from myCustomAdapter -->
    <TextView> ... </TextView> <!-- this is my btnChangeMode -->
<FrameLayout>
```

nothing fancy in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    List listItems =  ... // some method that gets objects from Database
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_id);
    listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this, listItems));
}
```

I have a custom adapter that basically has two types of rows header & item. In the "header" row, I have button "btnAddListItems" that allows me to add items into the list view. I want this button to be visible only in admin mode.

I've overridden the necessary methods in myCustomAdapter (getviewTypeCount, getItemViewType, getCount and getView). here's the getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (row == null) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
            return getHeaderRow();
        } else {
            return getItemRow();
        }
    }

    if (getItemViewType(position) == ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ROW) {
        MyHolder holder = (MyHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateNewContent(); 
    }

    return row;
}

....

private View getHeaderRow() {
    View lRow = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_header, null);

    mViewMode = new DetailsViewMode((Activity) getContext(), getChangeViewModeListener(lRow));
    return lRow;
}
```

So mViewMode here is a convenience POJO class i wrote that contains btnChangeMode, a boolean variable that indicates current mode (isAdmin) and the caller activity. I don't believe there's anything specific to my problem, so i'm not including that code here. Will be glad to if someone thinks that'll help.

```
private ChangeViewModeFragment.ChangeViewModeListener getChangeViewModeListener(final View headerRow) {
    return new ChangeViewModeFragment.ChangeViewModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewModeChanged(boolean isViewModeAdmin) {
            mViewMode.changeViewModeButtonText(isViewModeAdmin);
            toggleAdminFeatures(isViewModeAdmin, headerRow);
        }
    };
}

private void toggleAdminFeatures(boolean isViewModeAdmin, View headerRow) {
    TextView btnAddListItems = (TextView) headerRow.findViewById(R.id.add_button_id);

    if (isViewModeAdmin) {
        btnAddListItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnAddListItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

This is the part that's not working as it should. btnAddListItems is always visible within my listview.

btnChangeMode is within my activity so to speak, while the btnAddListItems is within my Adapter (ListView). But my requirement necessitates this behavior of having the listner of an activity, change the row state of my listview.

I suspect that when i change the visibility of my header row's button, I don't have hold of the correct header row instance, if that makes sense :P.

NitroNbg's suggestion of having a private button didn't work, which leads me to believe that maybe the ListView just needs a kickstart to get refreshed?

But I've tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() at the end of my toggleAdminFeatures method but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: what i'd do, is that in my POJO i would add a boolean type method, isUserAdmin, that method will get value true or false according to button in your activity.Then in getView of adapter, i'd check, if user is admin then set buttons visibility to visible otherwise invisible. If I am getting you right :/

Comment: that's basically what happens in the ChangeListener. the onViewModeChanged method gets called (and i've confirmed this with debugging), my POJO(mViewMode) checks and then sets the text depending on the mode.It then goes on to call the toggleAdminFeatures method (which is what i think is not achieving its purpose). This all happens when i return my headerView, which happens in the getView method.As an aside, doesn't getView get called only when i scroll/change or the rows get recycled? My viewMode button is part of the activity, and so it never triggers a call to getView. Hope i'm making sense.

Comment: Where is `mViewMode` declared? I think you probably overwrite it each time the adapter refreshes your "header view". Btw. ListView has method addHeaderView which does what you want to do the easier way :).

Comment: @TomaszGawel I was meddling around with the code and i think you're suspicion is probably right. when i call notifyDataSetChanged, mViewMode gets refreshed, which explains why it isn't working there. Changing the btn visibility though, doesn't seem to have an effect on the listview unless i force a refresh on the listview (which is what i would ideally like). :D thanks for the tip on addHeaderView. live and learn ><

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the following - create a private `Button` within your adapter class and within your getView() method, put a reference to `btnAddListItems` to it.

```
private Button buttonToHide;
//...
public View getView(...) {
    //...
    buttonToHide = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.add_button_id);
    //...
}
```

Then, inside your `ChangeViewModeListener()` simply refer to a method of your adapter class (of course you'll have to write it) that sets the `buttonToHide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Hopefully, since it's within the adapter it would be accessible.

EDIT: Just to point out if it isn't obvious - **only refer to the button that's in the header row**.

Comment: Ah i did try that. but that doesn't seem to have an effect either :( Does this mean that, I'm getting hold of the correct button, but for some reason, the view isn't getting refreshed?

Comment: I'd say yes, although I don't know what's the cause

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `notifyDataSetChanged()`, coz dataset hasn't changed, try setting the visiblity to `INVISIBLE`

Comment: Hmm I tried that but it's not helping. I don't think the issue is with INVISIBLE/GONE. I think the btnAddListItems that's being called through the listener for some reason isn't the same as the original one. if that makes sense :S